# Arrays with C++ CLR

Tags: arrays, c++-cli, clr

as we all know declaration of array is pretty simple

```
type name[size];
```

but when I compile my C++ as CLI/Winform It doesn't work, I've found the [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235236%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on MSDN which explains this new syntex, but for some reasone I still get strange errors.

When I declared the array the following way, it's compiled with no problems,but when ever the array is manipulated the program crash. (I tested it on a simple program with a button, still the same)

```
array<int>^ aiArray; //declaration - no problem
aiArray[0] = 5; //after executing it the program crash
```

Here is the error i get after the crash:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in test.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

Comment: At the risk of stating the obvious, you need an *instance* of `array<int>`, not just a variable declaration.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kewsb8ba(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: I haven't verified, but you could probably declare the variable with `array<int> aiArray(size);`.  The `^` character denotes a managed reference, essentially a pointer to a .NET object.  So your problematic code is roughly equivalent to `int* aiArray; aiArray[0] = 5;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create the array, not just declare a local variable. Try this:

```
array<int>^ aiArray;
aiArray = gcnew array<int>(10);
aiArray[0] = 5;
```

If you're familiar with C#, this should look familiar. If you're familiar with C++ and not C#, here's what's going on: What you have is roughly equivalent to `int* aiArray;` in unmanaged C++. You would need to do `aiArray = new int[10];` before you can use the unmanaged array.